# send sms in java web application by fetching data from database

Tags: java, oracle, sms, sms-gateway

I want to develop `SMS application` through java web i.e. in jsp, servlet and other things needed for sms application.

My requirement is: In my `database(oracle)` two columns i.e. `student_name and student_score` exist. If somebody wants to know his score then he will sms `STUDENT hisname to a number (let's say 1234)` then after receiving this sms, my java sms application will send his score by fetching score from database.

I need suggestions or ideas on how I can develop it? From where can I get a number like `1234` ?

User will `sms` as :

```
  STUDENT suresh to 1234
```

In my database score of suresh is `80` so `user will get score 80 in his mobile`

Answer (score 0):

I guess the phone number need to be confirmed and stored in your database. You can send SMS using a [Sms gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways.) providers.

Comment: Oh, I see you want to receive SMS, too. Using a SMS-to-Mail Gateway will help here where a SMS will get forwarded as an E-Mail.

Comment: here is a example but it is not working here, how can i get sms in mobile? http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=22

Comment: As your question is not clear about this, I had external services in mind that could be used to achieve what you where asking for.